# Android NDK compiler openssl occur error

Tags: android, c++, c

I tried to make simple test program with AES decryption using Android-OpenSSLibraries. The compiler/linker shows me an error. Compiler:

```
error: undefined reference to 'AES_set_encrypt_key'
error: undefined reference to 'AES_encrypt'
error: undefined reference to 'AES_set_decrypt_key'
```

And this is my Android.mk file,

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
$(info $(LOCAL_PATH))
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := demo
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I/some/include/path
LOCAL_LDLIBS := \
        -llog \
        -lz \
        -lm \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
       aes_api.c \
        io_module.cpp \
        jni_native.cpp \
        JniConstants.cpp \
        JNIHelp.cpp \
        libcrypto.so \
    PosixFile.cpp \

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/openssl
$(info  $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES))

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/libcrypto.so

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` content is incorrect. You must specify modules for it and not paths to shared objects.

You should have the following before defining this variable:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#Name it as you want, it doesn't matter. For consistency, let's name it LibCrypto
LOCAL_MODULE := LibCrypto 
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := <path/to/Libcrypto/includes>
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <path/to/libCrypto/shared/object>/libcrypto.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and then in your `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` you reference it directly with its module name:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := LibCrypto
```

Note that you can add more that one lib by defining other such "modules", that you can even build yourself beforehand (using `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`) and then reference multiple module the following way:

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := module1 \
                          module2 \
                          ...
```

I strongly encourage you to visit and keep this link about [**the Android.mk specification**](http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html)

Comment: yes,you're right.But I do as you say,the compiler shows me an another error:LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with ".a" The following file is unsupported: /libcrypto.so

Comment: @user4073982 That's strange, I use it, and moreover the doc for `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` explicitely says: "Unlike `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY` and `BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY`, the value of `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` must be a single path to a prebuilt shared library (e.g. `foo/libfoo.so`), instead of a source file."

Comment: Yes,LOCAL_SRC_FILES is a path of shared library,in mk file is LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCA_PATH)/libcrypto.so,but I don't know where is wrong?

Comment: Are you affirmative you actually used `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` and not accidentally `PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY`. It sounds like it could be the result of such a mistake.

Comment: Yes.Can you tell me your email,I send my demo to you.

Comment: No, sorry. You should find out that by yourself, or post additional information. That may even end up in another question if necessary, but seems now out of bounds of this particular question.

Comment: e...ok,I solve it by myself

Comment: include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := crypto_static
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I/some/include/path
LOCAL_LDLIBS := \
 -llog \
 -lz \
 -lm \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /libcrypto.so \
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/openssl

include $(LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES)   this is LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES

Comment: include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := demo
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -I/some/include/path
LOCAL_LDLIBS := \
 -llog \
 -lz \
 -lm \

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
       aes_api.c \
 io_module.cpp \
 jni_native.cpp \
 JniConstants.cpp \
 JNIHelp.cpp \
 libcrypto.so \
    PosixFile.cpp \

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/openssl

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := crypto_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) this is BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY,where wrong?

Comment: And error still is error: undefined reference to 'AES_decrypt'

Comment: No, no, no. You've done it wrong, reread my post. You should only have a `LOCAL_MODULE` which names it (also, why crypto_static for a shared lib?), a `LOCAL_SRC_FILE` which points to the `.so` file, possibly a `LOCAL_C_INCLUDE` which points to the includes, and then an `include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)`. Do not use `BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY`, you're not building anything here, you're just saying "Hey, here's a shared lib already built, remember it for later"

Comment: Yes,it's my fault,I haved solved it,thank you very much!